# How to redo an input if user enters invalid answer

Tags: python, input

I'm new to programming, and I was wondering how I can repeat an input section, if the user types in invalid data.

I want the application to just repeat the input section, instead of having to run the function all over again and making the user type everything all over again.

My guess is that I would have to change the "return main()" into something else.

```
condition = input("What is the condition of the phone(New or Used)?")
if condition not in ["New", "new", "Used", "used"]:
    print("Invalid input")
    return main()

gps = input("Does the phone have gps(Yes or No)?")
if gps not in ["Yes", "yes", "No", "no"]:
    print("Invalid input")
    return main()
```

Comment: take a look at the [while loop](https://wiki.python.org/moin/WhileLoop). Note: in the example it uses `raw_input()` which is for `python 2.7`. You *shoud* use `input()` if you have `python 3.4`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can generalise the code to use a message prompt and a validating function:

```
def validated_input(prompt, validate):
    valid_input = False
    while not valid_input:
        value = input(prompt)
        valid_input = validate(value)
    return value
```

eg:

```
>>> def new_or_used(value):
...     return value.lower() in {"new", "used"}

>>> validate_input("New, or used?", new_or_used)
```

Or, simpler, but less flexible, pass in the valid values:

```
def validated_input(prompt, valid_values):
    valid_input = False
    while not valid_input:
        value = input(prompt)
        valid_input = value.lower() in valid_values
    return value
```

And use:

```
>>> validate_input("New, or used?", {"new", "used"})
```

You could even use the valid values to create the input prompt:

```
def validated_input(prompt, valid_values):
    valid_input = False
    while not valid_input:
        value = input(prompt + ': ' + '/'.join(valid_values))
        valid_input = value.lower() in valid_values
    return value
```

Which gives a prompt:

```
>>> validate_input("What is the condition of the phone?", {"new", "used"})
What is the condition of the phone?: new/used
```

Answer (score 3):

You can make a method to check it in a loop:

```
def check_input(values,  message):
    while True:
        x = input(message) 
        if x in values:
            return x
        print "invalid values, options are "   + str(values)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a good reading about [Control Flows](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html).

Also in your case, you can use [`strip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip) and [`lower()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.lower) for user inputs.

```
>>> 'HeLLo'.lower()
'hello'
>>> ' hello   '.strip()
'hello'
```

Here is the solution for Python 3:

```
while True:
    condition=input("What is the condition of the phone(New or Used)?")
    if condition.strip().lower() in ['new', 'used']:
        break
    print("Invalid input")

while True:
    gps=input("Does the phone have gps(Yes or No)?")
    if gps.strip().lower() in ['yes','no']:
        break
    print("Invalid input")
```

Comment: Don't write it that way. It makes you think in negatives, and duplicates code. Write `while True` and `break` if input is good.

Comment: I always think in negatives. What is wrong with it? :-) But I agree that it makes duplicate code, let me update my answer.